# in what countries is authorize.net direct post method supported

Tags: authorize.net

I cannot find any contact email on authorize.net website to ask them directly, maybe can somebody provide one.

Im interested in implementing authorize.net direct post method to work in australia.

Paypal has a similar payment method called "direct payments" but its not available in australia for some reason beyond me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming and would be best answered by Authorize.Net customer support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use DPM with Authorize.Net in Australia.  http://www.authorize.net/en-ANZ/

Comment: i understand that thats a link but where exactly does it say it supports DPM in those countries.Paypal doesnt.

Comment: @Snake21 If they offer their services in a country that means they offer *all* of their services unless they state otherwise.